# Design Pattern question - Implementing DAO pattern with Modern Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

We've inherited some code where there is a DAO pattern implemented as such:

---

```
interface DomainMapper<S, T> {
    T mapObjectModel(S source);
}
public abstract class AbstractDao<Source, Target> implements DomainMapper<Source, Target> {
    protected List<T> execute(SqlParameter params...) {
        // Executes some query
        public S mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) {
            // does the mapping
            S source = super.mapRow(rs, rowNum);
            T value = mapObjectModel(s);
        }
    }
}
public class SpecificDAO extends AbstractDAO<Source, Target> {
    // Other functions
    public Target mapObjectModel(Source s) {
         // Mapping implementation here
    }
}
```

We have about 20 DAO's implemented in the similar fashion.

Here's the question

1. There is a specific DAO that needs some kind of state to persist between calls.
   I mean, between every call to `mapObjectModel()` with the Source, I need to store some value that I will use during the next call.
   for e.g. imagine Parent - Child relation, the mapObjectModel will be called for every child with the Parent and I want to create an Object graph something like below.

   `public class Parent { private List<Child> children; }`

so, I want to create a "context" that I can refer to in the next call and get the Parent and add children to it.

What is the best and easy way to update the `mapObjectModel()` to carry state information between calls and with minimal change to the existing DAO's?

Is there a pattern that can solve this problem for me?

Thanks

EDIT:

I want to be able to save some context between each call to `mapObjectModel`.

The DB willl return something like

---

Parent         Child

---

1                   1

---

1                   2

---

What my SpecificDAO should return is an object of Parent with a List so every time the call is made to`mapObjectModel` with each row I want to know if I already have the Parent object created in which case I can keep adding childs

Comment: An instance variable?

Comment: What's the end goal? To call `ParentDao` and get parent with children or call `ChildDao` and get parent with children (which doesn't make much sense).  I would assume you'd call `ParentDao` which would then in turn call `ChildDao` to populate the list?  Maintaining the parent in the `ChildDao` would require caching, and you don't have a reference to `Child { Parent parent }` so what would you do with the `Parent` after?

Comment: I want to be able to save some context between each call to `mapObjectModel`.

The DB willl return something like
<BR>
Parent         Child <BR>
1                   1.      <BR>
1                   2       <BR>  

What my SpecificDAO should return is an object of Parent with a List<Child> so every time the call is made to`mapObjectModel` with each row I want to know if I already have the Parent object created in which case I can keep adding childs